# TextEncoder gives extra bytes and TextDecoder gives wrong string for bytes of array with negative values

Tags: javascript

```
  arr = new Int8Array([-1,-1],0); // gives [-1,-1]

  str = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(arr); // gives "��"

  res = new TextEncoder('utf-8').encode(str); // gives [239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189] instead of [-1,-1]
```

Its not working for negative values only.Perfectly working for positives. Any other options?

Answer (score 3):

**Part 1: Bytes aren't negative**

The TextDecoder interface operates on the underlying ArrayBuffer (a byte sequence) that the Int8Array view wraps.

This:

```
new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(new Int8Array([-1, -1]))
```

is the same as:

```
new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(new Int8Array([-1, -1]).buffer)
```

Which is an ArrayBuffer containing the bytes 0xFF, 0xFF. So that's the same as:

```
new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(new Uint8Array([255, 255]))
```

**Part 2: UTF-8 Decode**

0xFF is not a valid code sequence in UTF-8, so it decodes as an error. That results in the REPLACEMENT CHARACTER (U+FFFD). Since there are two 0xFF bytes you get U+FFFD U+FFFD or:

"��"

**Part 3: UTF-8 Encode**

Encoding U+FFFD as UTF-8 gives you the bytes 0xEF 0xBF 0xBD. So encoding a string with U+FFFD U+FFFD would give you the bytes 0xEF 0xBF 0xBD or in decimal: 239 191 189 239 191 189

... which is exactly what you got as the result.

So this is working exactly as specified.

**So... what's the problem?**

My guess is that you are assuming that you can encode any byte into a string. That's not how text encodings work. Text encodings define a mapping from elements of a string to a byte sequence.

Not all encodings can represent all elements of a string, but UTF-8 (and UTF-16) can represent all code points that can occur in a JavaScript string.

But the reverse is *not* true. Not all byte sequences correspond to characters. When invalid byte sequences are found an error occurs. By default, the TextDecoder API produces replacement characters (� U+FFFD), but you can use the `fatal` flag to make it throw an exception instead.